# What is the difference of declaring private static final long serialVersionUID = xxxxxxxxL in classes that implements Serializable

Tags: java, serialization

What is the effect of declaring a `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1945670924947820279L;` in a class that implements Serializable?

I remember that one may implement the class without specifying the long, or just `1L`. What is the difference?

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class KAS implements Serializable
{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1945670924947820279L;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not specify a version, the JVM will use some internal rules to try to work out on its own whether or not the serialized object and the version in its own classloader are compatible.  This can result in a situation where someone has an outdated jar but the deserialization still works, because the newer version of the class didn't change it in a way that is picked up as an incompatibility.  (Perhaps you fixed a bug in a method implementation but left all the fields alone.)

Alternately you can exploit it by doing something like setting the value to 1 and never changing it if you *want* people with outdated versions to still be able to use the data.

Comment: It's also worth noting that serializing an object does not serialize any static fields except this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to safely deserialize/serialize instances, each version of the class needs a unique `serialVersionUID`. The deserialization process checks this value when deserializing - if it doesn't match an exception is thrown, preventing the serialized data from being deserialized into the wrong version of the class.

If you make the `serialVersionUID` always the same value, you might as well not have it.

Comment: Actually, you can successfully serialize/deserialize without providing a serialVersionUID at all - the compiler adds one for you automatically based on the fields in the class. The value also does not need to be "unique". The main thing it is used for is throwing an exception if you attempt to deserialize an instance into an "incompatible" (i.e. different serialVersionUID) class definition. Most people don't really care about this anymore, because using serialization for long-lived persistence is generally now done using O/R mapping tools. But there are some use cases where it matters.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. The JVM will compute its own if you don't supply one. The reason for supplying one is to control it, not just to satisfy the JVM. @jkraybill the compiler doesn't supply it, the JVM does.

Comment: @EJP - thanks for the correction, I'm obviously a bit rusty! :)